# What is the maximum strength of a wildcard SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

i had an interesting conversation with a bank IT security employee, and they raised a few questions.

What is the maximum strength/bit length of a wildcard domain certificate?

Are they as secure? (in the encryption sense)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make certificates pretty strong, however not all browsers support encryption that strong. 16384 bits is valid, though getting a commercial certificate authority to issue one is another matter.

Fundamentally, wildcart certs are no different than non-wildcard certs from a technical point of view; they just have a "*." in their subject line.

Update:

Based on your comment, the bank person you were talking to is of the opinion that the *stream cipher* is restricted to 40-bit for wildcard certificates. This is not the case. My old job uses a wildcard certificate for most of their web-presences, and a little work with openssl shows that the cipher on those certs is "RC4-MD5" which is a 128-bit cipher.

The 40-bit limit may have been a limit with other SSL suites in webservers, browsers, or certificate-authority infrastructures, but is no longer a limit.

Comment: Some additional info: you can make key sizes as large as the signing CA will allow. Most these will allow a max of 4096 bit keys.

Comment: I understand this - thanks for the reply.

The bank security guy in question informed us we couldn't have a wildcard SSL certificate because they didn't allow a bit length of greater than 40-bit... ? (which was the first i'd heard of it and obviously the reason i asked this question)

Comment: 40-bit is a stream cypher, and a rather weak one at that. I'm sure this guy is confused. The certs issued by CAs are public/private keys, they're very long, typically the shortest would be 512-bits long. The public/private keys (certificates) are used to determine a session symmetric key (for the stream cypher, which will be used to actually encrypt data during the session). Stream cyphers - like AES, Blowfish, RC4, 3DES - use much shorter key lengths from 40-bits up to 512-bits. Typically 128 or 256 are used these days.

Comment: @Doug: **Two decades ago** there _was_ a relationship where special certificates were required for SSL (not yet TLS) to use 'strong' encryption, which was indeed defined as over 40-bit symmetric or 512-bit RSA; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-Gated_Cryptography

Answer (score -2):

You also have to take into account, how log the certificate is vald. The shorter the time span, the shorter the bit length of the certificate is. A wildcard certificate will be prone to multiple sites rather, hence will receiver more attention on the web.

Comment: No, this is nonsense. There is no relationship between the key length of a certificate and its validity duration.

Comment: So would you argue, that a weak certificate - say.. an 8bit would take equally long time to dis mental as an 2048bit long one?

Comment: No. That's not what the validity duration means.

Comment: 'dis mental' does not make sense in English; I assume you meant 'break'. Key length or size is related to strength but not the same; RSA or DSA requires 2048-bit size for roughly 112-bit strength, currently acceptable, but ECC requires only 224-bit size (although 256-bit is commonly used mostly because of NSA's promotion of P-256 and P-384). And @duskwuff a certificate's expiration should not be longer than the key is expected to be safe, but it can be and usually is shorter; current keys are expected to last beyond 2030 but certs are commonly 1 year and rarely more than 3.

Comment: There is pretty much a broadly accepted minimum key size of 2048 bits for RSA keys, irrespective of its use in a cert, or indeed, irrespective of pretty much anything (it might still be the case people generate 1024 bit keys for testing, but even that is I suspect becoming less common). Anything below 2048 bits is considered insufficiently secure for use in the real world. I also don't see this mentioned, but any number of certificates can potentially be requested based on a single key - unless a CA specifically checks for that.